# SQL Subquery with a COUNT

Tags: sql-server

I have a table of our communications containing; Created User, Created Date & Sub Code.  I want the output to have 4 columns in SSRS, showing communications from the previous month;

```
Comms logged    Dealt With     % Dealt With
Created         User              1    
Created         User              2
```

So far I've got;

```
SELECT
  [EM-COMMUNICATION].[CRT-USER]
  ,COUNT([EM-COMMUNICATION].[CRT-USER]) AS LOGGED
  ,(SELECT COUNT([EM-COMMUNICATION].[CRT-USER]) FROM [EM-COMMUNICATION] WHERE [EM-COMMUNICATION].[SUB-CODE] = N'DEALTWITH' AND DateDiff(MONTH,[EM-COMMUNICATION].[CRT-DATE],GetDate()) = 1) AS Dealt
FROM
  [EM-COMMUNICATION]
WHERE
  DateDiff(MONTH,[EM-COMMUNICATION].[CRT-DATE],GetDate()) = 1
GROUP BY
  [EM-COMMUNICATION].[CRT-USER]
```

The problem I'm having is that the sub query is returning a count of comms for all users, instead of matching the groupings of the main query, i.e., each row has the same count in 'Dealt With'

Answer (score 0):

You need to relate your subquery with your main query using `AND [EM-COMMUNICATION].[CRT-USER] =  T.[CRT-USER]`

```
SELECT
  [EM-COMMUNICATION].[CRT-USER]
  ,COUNT([EM-COMMUNICATION].[CRT-USER]) AS LOGGED
  ,(SELECT COUNT([EM-COMMUNICATION].[CRT-USER]) FROM [EM-COMMUNICATION] as T WHERE T.[SUB-CODE] = N'DEALTWITH' AND DateDiff(MONTH,T.[CRT-DATE],GetDate()) = 1 AND [EM-COMMUNICATION].[CRT-USER] =  T.[CRT-USER]) AS Dealt
FROM
  [EM-COMMUNICATION]
WHERE
  DateDiff(MONTH,[EM-COMMUNICATION].[CRT-DATE],GetDate()) = 1
GROUP BY
  [EM-COMMUNICATION].[CRT-USER]
```

Comment: Just tried this and I am getting the error; Subquery returned more than 1 value, This is not permitted when the subquery follows =,!=,<,<=,>,>= or when the subquery is used as an expression

Comment: my subquery return only one result. I believe that you are using different version of it